Who is Gordon Dioxide?
I gave a family member a copy of the new out-of-print Gordon Dioxide's Book of Slightly Odd Bedtime Stories for Christmas this year (which they've liked for a long time).
She recalls that the author's web site (which is now offline, and even Wayback Machine didn't help me) used to have the stories on it, but doesn't recall if it had any other biographical details on the author.
Who was Gordon Dioxide? Does anyone have biographical details on him, such as his real name, birthplace, age, educational background, etc.?
